Screen flickering when wake up from lock screen if multiple monitors are connected
My system is Ubuntu 23.10 with 6.5.0-41-generic kernel.
My hardware is a ROG Strix laptop with three monitors: the built-in, HDMI-connected, and a monitor connected through the type-C port.

If I lock the screen, the screen will flicker when I log in again and it will never stop.
Disconnecting the type-C port and replugging it will solve the issue. This is a little inconvenient though.
Not sure what causes this issue.

It's a problem with the screen refreshing rate.
Normally, I can set three monitors with different refreshing rates say 165Hz, 240Hz, and 60 Hz. However, this causes a problem when waking up the computer.
Switching the refreshing rate of the built-in monitor from 240Hz to 60Hz solves this issue.
